# Minimize Space Between Header Image and Blog Post

Tags: html, css, padding

I would like to shrink the space between my header image and blog content, specifically directly above the date/title entry on my most recent posts. How can I do this?

The site is: http://www.studywithstyleblog.com

And below is some of the code:

```
.header-outer {
background: $(header.background.color) $(header.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -400px;
_background-image: none;
}
.Header h1 {
font: $(header.font);
color: $(header.text.color);
text-shadow: $(header.shadow.offset.left) $(header.shadow.offset.top) $(header.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.Header h1 a {
color: $(header.text.color);
}
.Header .description {
font-size: $(description.text.size);
color: $(description.text.color);
}
.header-inner .Header .titlewrapper {
padding: 22px $(header.padding);
}
.header-inner .Header .descriptionwrapper {
padding: 0 $(header.padding);
}
```

and

```
.date-header span {
background-color: $(date.header.background.color);
font-size: 12px;
color: $(date.header.color);
padding: $(date.header.padding);
margin: $(date.header.margin);
}
.main-inner {
padding-top: $(main.padding.top);
padding-bottom: $(main.padding.bottom);
}
.main-inner .column-center-inner {
padding: 0 $(main.padding);
}
.main-inner .column-center-inner .section {
margin: 0 $(main.section.margin);
}
.post {
margin: 0 0 $(post.margin.bottom) 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In your `.main-inner` class there is a `padding-top:35px` says Firebug. If you manipulate this value you can minimize the gap to whatever distance you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.region-inner.main-inner{
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Or set it to a small value of your choice. But this is the CSS property you need to manipulate.